# Understanding how pattern matching works in Coq

Tags: pattern-matching, coq

I'm currently following the [Software Foundations](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/) book, I am currently on the **Lists chapter.**
However, I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a specific case of pattern matching and, due to being a beginner in Coq, I'm not sure about how to find the answer of this question.

So, the exercise was to create a `Fixpoint` to calculate how many nat `v` we have in a list `s` (a bag, more specifically).

I decided to use pattern matching for this, but if I tried to define a function like this:

```
Fixpoint count' (v: nat) (s: bag) : nat :=
  match s with
  | nil => O
  | h :: t => match h with
              | v => S (count' v t)
              end
  end.
```

and tried to apply this function to, let's say,

```
Example test_count1: count' 1 [1;2;3;1;4;1] = 3.
```

I would end up with `6 = 3`. My understanding is that matching `h` with `v` is always "true", so it ends up counting every element of the list.

But why does it happen? How could we compare, using pattern matching, the values of both `h` and `v`?

**PS:** I have already solved this exercise using an auxiliary function that compares if `h` and `v` are equal, but I'm wondering if this can be achieved only using built-in pattern matching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern

```
match h with
| v => S (count' v t)
end
```

introduces a new variable `v` bound to `h`, shadowing the existing `v`. It is equivalent to a `let` expression:

```
let v := h in S (count' v t)
(* or, without shadowing *)
let v1 := h in S (count' v1 t)
```

Instead, to compare `h` and `v`, use a comparison function:

```
if h =? v then ... else ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Pattern matching is useful when you want to make case distinctions on constructors. Perhaps the name is misleading in this sense, since

```
match h with
| v => ...
end
```

will not compare `h` and the specific `v` from above. Instead, the `match` checks to see if the shape of `h` matches the shape exemplified by `v`. Like Li-yao Xia mentioned, here `v` has no shape, it is a universal placeholder. On the other hand something like

```
match h with
| O => ...
| S k => ...
end
```

exposes two different shapes that a `nat` can have, namely being `O` or the successor of some `k`. The latter is the kind of situation where we do want to use `match`. Comparing values is best done through `_ =? _`.